# Запятая перед союзом И в сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед И в таком предложении: "Мы любим наш театр, наших зрителей(?) и надеемся, что лучшие спектакли у нас еще впереди."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Любим* и *надеемся* - однородные сказуемые, соединенные союзом *и*. Запятая не нужна (хотя там и слышится пауза):

**Мы любим наш театр, наших зрителей и надеемся, что лучшие спектакли у нас еще впереди.**

Comment: Если пауза слышится, то можно и запятую поставить, тогда это сложное предложение, во второй части пропущено подлежащее.